# $[K:K\cap \mathbb{R}]$ for $K$ a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of rational numbers. 
How do I prove that $[K:K\cap \mathbb{R}] \leq 2$, where $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the field of real numbers?

I could prove the result when $K$ is a finite extension or a simple extension, but could not find a general proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ and let $\rho\in G$ represent the *"complex conjugation"* automorphism. Then either $\rho=\mathrm{id}$ or $\rho$ has order $2$, so that $H=\langle \rho\rangle$ has cardinality $\leq 2$, so that 
$$[K:K\cap \mathbb{R}]=[K:K^H]=|H|\leq 2$$

Comment: Oh right, this was easy. Thanks. I was going along the following lines: I claimed that if $B$ and $A$ are 2 fields containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $B\subseteq A$, then $[B:B\cap \mathbb{R}] \leq [A:A\cap\mathbb{R}]$. But that got me no where.